# What does the word "fair" in this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> A majority of the students who attend the job fair expressed interest in becoming doctors or lawyers.

What does the word "fair" in this sentence mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is what "job fair" means:
[Merriam-Webster "job fair"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/job%20fair)

> an event where employers offer information about their companies to people who are looking for jobs

This is an extension of one of the basic meanings of "fair" as a noun:
[Merriam-Webster "fair"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fair)

> 1  a gathering of buyers and sellers at a particular place and time for trade